International stocks and options exchange
I was thinking about the idea of an international trading platform on which you can trade anything from around the world from different stock exchanges, all in one place. I come from an engineering and a coding background.
I have little to no knowledge about its execution and what are the litigation difficulties in executing this plan. I hope that you will enlighten me with some of your knowledge regarding this matter.
If it is possible then why big corporate brokers have not done it yet?

Since there are no quantitative reasons not to, I suggest that https://economics.stackexchange.com may be a better venue for this question.

It is possible and it does exist e.g. IBKR

Yes it already exists, nothing new here.
